# Ho to generate random code and insert into mysql table

Tags: php

I have the following insert query, I am unable to put the random code in this. Please help me out.

```
("insert into users (UserName,UserType,AgencyID,Email,Password,Cpassword,CityID,Address,Mobile,OTP,Approval)    values 
    ('$users->UserName','$users->UserType',$users->AgencyID,'$users->Email','$users->Password','$users->Cpassword',$users->CityID,'$users->Address','$users->Mobile','$users->OTP','$users->Approval')");
```

Comment: pls explain us how your code behaves and how it should behave.

Comment: Where should random code be inserted?

Comment: 1. Add a new column `random_code`.
2. Create a random code using php.
3. Insert this into ypur table.

Comment: right now I am manually entering the "OTP" field, but what I exactly need is the "OTP" has to be automatically get inserted into db along with mobile, that too by generating random code.

Comment: Instead of random_code, I want to use OTP

Comment: What error are  you getting

Comment: So,  create it by using php and get it into a variable and insert to your table

Comment: I am not getting any error, I just want to know how put that random code in this insert query

Comment: well... you are passing some $users variable with OTP field, you should set it there... thats what you are asking?

Comment: if its a normal insert query there would not have a big problem for me, but I am dealing with oops, so I am facing little problem

Comment: if you want just value then use rand(1, 10) or something or before insert just do $users->OTP = rand(1, 10); i'm not sure what are you doing

Comment: this might be working, but it is inserting rand(1, 10); this into db

Comment: Have u look around the solution for it or u directly ask the question . there r lots of example available already here'

Comment: <?php rand(1,10); ?> or close inverted commas... i cant see your code, you just gave very small sample of your code

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo session_id(); ?>" />


  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $EditList->OTP ; ?>" name="OTP"/>


      <input type="text" value="<?php echo $EditList->Mobile ; ?>" name="Mobile" id="Mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile No." onblur="mobile1(this.value)"/>

Comment: $result = $db->Query("insert into users (UserName,UserType,AgencyID,Email,Password,Cpassword,CityID,Address,Mobile,OTP,Approval) 
  values ('$users->UserName','$users->UserType',$users->AgencyID,'$users->Email','$users->Password','$users->Cpassword',$users->CityID,'$users->Address','$users->Mobile','$users->OTP','$users->Approval')");

Comment: change _'$users->OTP'_ with _".rand(1,10)."_ if it should be string then _'".rand(1,10)."'_

Comment: Hey its getting inserted, Thanks alot

Comment: what IDE are you using? for example netbeans can highlight your code (so you can easly end string and add some vars) ;) glad i could help see ya

Comment: Iam using dreamviewer, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with RAND().

Please refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Answer (score 0):

```
function createRandomPassword() { 

    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789"; 
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
    $i = 0; 
    $pass = '' ; 

    while ($i <= 7) { 
        $num = rand() % 33; 
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1); 
        $pass = $pass . $tmp; 
        $i++; 
    } 

    return $pass; 

} 

$random_code = createRandomPassword();



("insert into users (UserName,UserType,AgencyID,Email,Password,Cpassword,CityID,Address,Mobile,OTP,Approval)    values 
    ('$users->UserName','$users->UserType',$users->AgencyID,'$users->Email','$users->Password','$users->Cpassword',$users->CityID,'$users->Address','$users->Mobile','$random_code','$users->Approval')");
```